# SQL запрос с объединением табличек

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sqlite, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT accounts.pName,
    accounts.pOnline,
    accounts.pID, 
    accounts.pRank, 
    accounts.Last_Online 
    FROM accounts 
    Inner join army_soldiers ON accounts.pID = army_soldiers.pID
    AND army_soldiers.PlatoonID = 1  AND army_soldiers.SquadID = 1
            Inner join army_squads ON accounts.pID <> army_squads.ID_SCommander
```

(возвращается пустой запрос)
То есть, мне нужно выбрать данные из таблицы `accounts` а именно `pName pOnline pID pRank Last_Online` при условии если эти иды (`pID`) совпадают с идами в таблице `army_soldiers` `pID` ( И ЕСЛИ В ТАБЛИЦЕ `army_squads` НЕ РОВНЯЕТСЯ данным в сущностях `accounts.pID` и `army_squads.ID_SCommander`)

---

Запрос вроде верный, но ВСЕГДА возвращает 0 строк если значение в таблице army_squads.ID_SCommander равно NULL в противном случае - работает безупречно

Comment: Публикуйте - DDL таблиц (CREATE TABLE), пример наполнения (INSERT INTO) и требуемый на этих данных результат.

Comment: Вы можете [редактировать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1108958/edit) свой вопрос. Не нужно правки публиковать отдельным ответом.